# listmetadata command returns nothing on 7.129 sfdx version for CustomField

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error, mac-os-x

i have os x sfdx version 7.129 (latest) (also linux version) and when i run on all envs we have this command:
`sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m CustomField -u env1 -a 53.0 --json`

it return nothing

```bash
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": []
}
```

but other types seems fine.

on sfdx v. 7.124 the command works ok. Where can I report bug? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can report issues in the [forcedotcom/cli](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues) repository.

There already appears to be one related to your [specific issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1285). The initial post directly mentions `ListView`, but many other components are listed (`CustomField` being another one) in a comment as being affected (metadata sub-components).

I believe a [fix](https://github.com/salesforcecli/plugin-source/pull/309) was completed in the plugin source and should be included in the [next CLI release](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1285#issuecomment-976803132) which should be tomorrow ([Thursday](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/sfdx/README.md))

Update: version 7.130.1 (from the update mentioned above) should fix this issue.